# Video Won't play

Tags: qt

I am using QMediaPlayer to create a custom media player.  The program compiles but when I try to play a "wmv" I get the following error:

```
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:videos/Wildlife.wmv"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:videos/Wildlife.wmv"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:videos/Wildlife.wmv"
Error: "Could not open resource for reading."
Error playing video1: Could not open resource for reading.
```

I have installed GStreamer and Codecs on the system.  This same code does work under Windows, so it is only Linux that has the issue.

Before I try to play the file, I have a check that insures that the file does exist.

The version of Gstreamer is gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 0.10.13-1

Thanks,
Bear

Comment: Try to set full path: `QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(fileUrl).absoluteFilePath())` or set full path by hand

Comment: Ok now I am getting the following:
(MAST:2289): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state: assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
Error: "Internal data stream error."

Comment: Does the file play with another other media player on the Linux system?

Comment: What version of GStreamer are you using?  Qt is built against the older v0.1x series: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33400

Comment: @cmannett85  Yes it does play with another media player.   The version of Gstreamer is gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg 0.10.13-1.